# How is sorted set ordered without Ordering provided and how does the equality of elements work with Ordering

Tags: scala

I have two confusions about sorted set,

- if we don't provide an Ordering to the elements, and the element has no default ordering such as integer or strings do, then how is the underlying sorted set sorted?
- if we defined the ordering, then how is the comparison for equality one? using the default equal method or the one defined in compare method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no `Ordering` in scope when you instantiate a `SortedSet`, that is a compilation error.

Try it in the REPL:

```
scala> collection.SortedSet[Object]()
<console>:8: error: No implicit Ordering defined for Object.
              collection.SortedSet[Object]()
                                      ^
```

`Ordering` defines equality. From [the scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering):

> def equiv(x: T, y: T): Boolean
>
> Return true if x == y in the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you don't provide an ordering and there's no default ordering available, you'll get a compiler error:

```
  case class DoesntWork(i:Int)

  //error: No implicit Ordering defined for DoesntWork.
  val doesntWork = SortedSet(DoesntWork(1), DoesntWork(2))
```

Second, I'm confused by what you're trying to say here, but you need to implement your own compare function for custom types:

```
  implicit val worksNowOrdering = new Ordering[DoesntWork]{
    def compare(x: DoesntWork, y: DoesntWork): Int = {
      if (x.i < y.i) -1
      else if (x.i > y.i) 1
      else 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you do not provide Ordering and none is found in implicit scope for type of elements you want to store in SortedSet it will not compile.
2. I am not sure, but I bet for ==, which will be default one

Comment: `==` should result in `0`, `1` implies that the first object is greater than the second.